# Backbone.js + require.js : Wait until file is loaded

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm using backbone.js and require.js. I have a script with files dependencies but the problem is that a file is not loaded before executing my script. So, a function is not defined. Here is the code exemple :

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'jqueryUi',
    'holder',
    'knob',
    'jquery.ui.widget',
    'iframeTransport',
    'fileupload',
    'knobScript',
], function($, ui, Holder) {

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#upload').fileupload({...}); // This one is unedefined because the script from the file fileupload is not completely loaded
   });
});
```

Is someone has a solution to be sure that the script fileuplaod called in define is fully loaded before executing the script with the function (functionFromFileupload) ?

Thank for your help

Comment: could u please attach `fileupload` code ?

Comment: You could check to see if the module is loaded using `if (require.specified('fileupload')) { ... }`

Comment: @Evgeniy https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.fileupload.js

Comment: @chridam This test only check if the module is loaded, so if not, my function will not be called right ?

Comment: 1 ) as it JQ plugin u should use it as `$('#some').fileupload` 2) dont forget to define plugin and its dependence from JQ in `require.config` in `paths` and `shim` sections

Answer (score 0):

To complement Evgeniy's comment: The problem is not that `fileupload` is loaded after your function. It **will** be loaded before running your function, that is the contract of Require. (If you can confirm it doesn't, then it would probably be a misconfiguration or less probably a bug of Require.)

Most probably the problem is that, sometimes, `fileupload` may be loaded *before* jQuery. Thus, it does not find the `jQuery` object to plug to and `$(...).fileupload(...)` fails. Use shim in the Require configuration, e.g. as:

```
require.config({
    ...
    shim: {
        fileupload: {
            deps: ["jquery"]
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
});
```

You will probably have to shim other things too, e.g. jQueryUI.